# imagick binary to count number of pages in a pdf file

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, imagick

Could someone suggest the php code using exec() function to execute a binary of imagick to count the pages in a pdf file.
Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that ImageMagick uses ghostscript to slurp pdf files, so this may be a grossly inefficient way to simply count pages.

What I do is use pdftk to burst the pages, then count the number of output files.  But it happens that I also want to process the output files.

You can also use pdftk's data dump to count the pages.

This command line works nicely on *nix.

```
pdftk myfile.pdf dump_data | grep NumberOfPages | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use identify that comes with ImageMagick:

```
$pages = exec("/usr/bin/identify -format %n <filename>");
```